# Image Cropping with transformation matrix?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I am training a neural network to do Human Single Pose Estimation on the MPII dataset. Within it, many images contain more than one person and I need to crop the image in order to extract each single person.
Of each I have the position (or center) and the scale w.r.t. 200 px height.
This code does just what I need:

```
def get_transform(center, scale, res, rot=0):
    # Generate transformation matrix
    h = 200 * scale
    t = np.zeros((3, 3))
    t[0, 0] = float(res[1]) / h
    t[1, 1] = float(res[0]) / h
    t[0, 2] = res[1] * (-float(center[0]) / h + .5)
    t[1, 2] = res[0] * (-float(center[1]) / h + .5)
    t[2, 2] = 1
    if not rot == 0:
        rot = -rot # To match direction of rotation from cropping
        rot_mat = np.zeros((3,3))
        rot_rad = rot * np.pi / 180
        sn,cs = np.sin(rot_rad), np.cos(rot_rad)
        rot_mat[0,:2] = [cs, -sn]
        rot_mat[1,:2] = [sn, cs]
        rot_mat[2,2] = 1
        # Need to rotate around center
        t_mat = np.eye(3)
        t_mat[0,2] = -res[1]/2
        t_mat[1,2] = -res[0]/2
        t_inv = t_mat.copy()
        t_inv[:2,2] *= -1
        t = np.dot(t_inv,np.dot(rot_mat,np.dot(t_mat,t)))
    return t

def transform(pt, center, scale, res, invert=0, rot=0):
    # Transform pixel location to different reference
    t = get_transform(center, scale, res, rot=rot)
    if invert:
        t = np.linalg.inv(t)
    new_pt = np.array([pt[0], pt[1], 1.]).T
    new_pt = np.dot(t, new_pt)
    return new_pt[:2].astype(int)

def crop(img, center, scale, res, rot=0):
    # Upper left point
    ul = np.array(transform([0, 0], center, scale, res, invert=1))
    # Bottom right point
    br = np.array(transform(res, center, scale, res, invert=1))

    new_shape = [br[1] - ul[1], br[0] - ul[0]]
    if len(img.shape) > 2:
        new_shape += [img.shape[2]]
    new_img = np.zeros(new_shape)

    # Range to fill new array
    new_x = max(0, -ul[0]), min(br[0], len(img[0])) - ul[0]
    new_y = max(0, -ul[1]), min(br[1], len(img)) - ul[1]
    # Range to sample from original image
    old_x = max(0, ul[0]), min(len(img[0]), br[0])
    old_y = max(0, ul[1]), min(len(img), br[1])
    new_img[new_y[0]:new_y[1], new_x[0]:new_x[1]] = img[old_y[0]:old_y[1], old_x[0]:old_x[1]]

    return cv2.resize(new_img, res)
```

However, I haven't figured out what kind of transformation matrix it is (the one that was created to derive ul or br).
Could someone explain to me what happens in these functions?
Thank you

Comment: the matrix is 3x3, so it _could_ have been a full homography. a 2x3 matrix would be an affine matrix. this matrix however only contains translation and scaling. -- the code is awful. incredibly convoluted, needlessly complicated. badly named variables. not self-explaining, and the lack of comments doesn't make up for it either. -- where's that code from? who wrote it? maybe they can answer.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Hi! Thanks for your reply. I took this code from [this repository](https://github.com/princeton-vl/pytorch_stacked_hourglass/blob/master/utils/img.py). [Other repositories](https://github.com/zhiqiangdon/CU-Net/blob/master/pylib/HumanAug.py) use the same functions.

Comment: ok so a high level overview... `get_transform` builds the transformation matrix. it starts from an identity (`eye` meaning `I`, for identity). it fills in the last column with translation values. the diagonal receives scaling factors. the last row stays as is. `transform` just applies the matrix to one point. it converts it from `(x,y)` to `(x,y,1)` before calculating the multiplication. `crop` picks two opposite corners of a bounding box, transforms them, and then calculates a new bounding box from the transformed corner points. since it uses numpy slicing, it has to clip the coordinates.